# Merging social care expenditure data to NHS trust data

Tags: data-format

I have downloaded social care expenditure from the following website http://content.digital.nhs.uk/article/1165/Search-catalogue?topics=1/Social%20care/Social%20care%20expenditure&sort=Date&size=10&page=1#top

The social care expenditure data are given by councils. I however want to merge this data to NHS Trusts data so that I can determine the level of expenditure on each council or councils in which the NHS trust operates or is located on.

I have tried numerous ways but to no avail.

Can you please have or have some suggestions on how to perform the merge.